# Can Mixpanel be used natively on watchOS 2.0?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, ios-app-extension, mixpanel, watchos-2

I have a watchOS 2.0 app that I want to track events with in Mixpanel. I'm using the Mixpanel pod [version 2.8.3](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone/releases). In an earlier released they introduced support for App Extensions, including WatchKit.

My podfile looks like this:

```
target 'Elevate', :exclusive => true do
 platform :ios, '8.0'
 ...
 pod 'Mixpanel', '~> 2.8.3'
 ...
end

target 'Dash 2 Extension', :exclusive => true do
 platform :watchos, '2.0'
 xcodeproj 'griffin.xcodeproj'
 pod 'Mixpanel/AppExtension"
end
```

But Xcode says `it doesn't contain platform 'watchsimulator' in its SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS 'iphonesimulator, iphoneos'`

Answer (score 0):

After trying to [fork mixpanel-iphone](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone/compare/master...dmzza:watchOS-2.0) and adding support for watchOS 2 myself [as described by Cocoapods](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.38/), I've decided that it wasn't worth it. They have too many dependencies on UIKit.

Instead I intend to send a message for each event to my iPhone App using WatchConnectivity and then track the events from the iPhone App.

I hope Mixpanel adds native support for watchOS 2 soon.